# External usb 3.0 hard drive is not recognised when plugged into usb 3 port

Tags: usb, usb-drive, hard-drive

I have an Iomega Prestige Portable External Hard Drive 1TB USB 3.0.

It works fine on windows 7 as a usb 3.0 drive.

It isn't detected on ubuntu natty 64bit, 2.6.38-8-generic.

fdisk -l cannot see it at all:

```
    Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x1bed746b

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1        1689    13560832   27  Unknown
/dev/sda2   *        1689        1702      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda3            1702       19978   146805760    7  HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda4           19978       60802   327914497    5  Extended
/dev/sda5           25555       60802   283120640    7  HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda6           19978       23909    31571968   83  Linux
/dev/sda7           23909       25555    13218816   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Partition table entries are not in disk order
```

lsusb can see it:

```
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 059b:0070 Iomega Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 05fe:0011 Chic Technology Corp. Browser Mouse
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0489:e00f Foxconn / Hon Hai 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0c45:64b5 Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 08ff:168f AuthenTec, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

And dmesg | grep -i xhci (I may have unplugged the drive and plugged it back in again after booting):

```
[    1.659060] pci 0000:04:00.0: xHCI HW did not halt within 2000 usec status = 0x0
[   11.484971] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 18 (level, low) -> IRQ 18
[   11.484997] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: setting latency timer to 64
[   11.485002] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: xHCI Host Controller
[   11.485064] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 3
[   11.636149] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: irq 18, io mem 0xc5400000
[   11.636241] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: irq 43 for MSI/MSI-X
[   11.636246] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: irq 44 for MSI/MSI-X
[   11.636251] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: irq 45 for MSI/MSI-X
[   11.636256] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: irq 46 for MSI/MSI-X
[   11.636261] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: irq 47 for MSI/MSI-X
[   11.639654] xHCI xhci_add_endpoint called for root hub
[   11.639655] xHCI xhci_check_bandwidth called for root hub
[   11.956366] usb 3-1: new SuperSpeed USB device using xhci_hcd and address 2
[   12.001073] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: WARN: short transfer on control ep
[   12.007059] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: WARN: short transfer on control ep
[   12.012932] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: WARN: short transfer on control ep
[   12.018922] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: WARN: short transfer on control ep
[   12.049139] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: WARN: short transfer on control ep
[   12.056754] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: WARN: short transfer on control ep
[   12.131607] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: WARN no SS endpoint bMaxBurst
[   12.179717] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: WARN: short transfer on control ep
[   12.686876] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: WARN: babble error on endpoint
[   12.687058] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: WARN Set TR Deq Ptr cmd invalid because of stream ID configuration
[   12.687152] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: ERROR Transfer event for disabled endpoint or incorrect stream ring
[   43.330737] usb 3-1: reset SuperSpeed USB device using xhci_hcd and address 2
[   43.422579] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: WARN: short transfer on control ep
[   43.422658] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff88014669af00
[   43.422665] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff88014669af40
[   43.422671] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff88014669af80
[   43.422677] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff88014669afc0
[   43.531159] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: WARN no SS endpoint bMaxBurst
[  125.160248] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: WARN no SS endpoint bMaxBurst
[  903.766466] usb 3-1: new SuperSpeed USB device using xhci_hcd and address 3
[  903.807789] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: WARN: short transfer on control ep
[  903.813530] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: WARN: short transfer on control ep
[  903.819400] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: WARN: short transfer on control ep
[  903.825104] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: WARN: short transfer on control ep
[  903.855067] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: WARN: short transfer on control ep
[  903.862314] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: WARN: short transfer on control ep
[  903.862597] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: WARN no SS endpoint bMaxBurst
[  903.913211] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: WARN: short transfer on control ep
[  904.424416] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: WARN: babble error on endpoint
[  904.424599] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: WARN Set TR Deq Ptr cmd invalid because of stream ID configuration
[  904.424700] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: ERROR Transfer event for disabled endpoint or incorrect stream ring
[  935.139021] usb 3-1: reset SuperSpeed USB device using xhci_hcd and address 3
[  935.226075] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: WARN: short transfer on control ep
[  935.226140] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff880148186b00
[  935.226148] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff880148186b40
[  935.226153] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff880148186b80
[  935.226159] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff880148186bc0
[  935.343339] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: WARN no SS endpoint bMaxBurst
```

I thought it might be that the firmware wasn't compatible with linux or something, but when booting a live image of partedmagic, (2.6.38.4-pmagic), the drive was detected fine, I could mount it and got usb 3.0 speeds (at least they double the speeds I got from plugging same drive in usb 2 ports).

dmesg in partedmagic did say something about no SuperSpeed endpoint which was an error I saw in a previous dmesg of ubuntu:

```
Jun 27 15:49:02 (none) user.info kernel: [    2.978743] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 18 (level, low) -> IRQ 18
Jun 27 15:49:02 (none) user.debug kernel: [    2.978771] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: setting latency timer to 64
Jun 27 15:49:02 (none) user.info kernel: [    2.978781] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: xHCI Host Controller
Jun 27 15:49:02 (none) user.info kernel: [    2.978856] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 3
Jun 27 15:49:02 (none) user.info kernel: [    3.089458] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: irq 18, io mem 0xc5400000
Jun 27 15:49:02 (none) user.debug kernel: [    3.089541] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: irq 42 for MSI/MSI-X
Jun 27 15:49:02 (none) user.debug kernel: [    3.089544] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: irq 43 for MSI/MSI-X
Jun 27 15:49:02 (none) user.debug kernel: [    3.089546] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: irq 44 for MSI/MSI-X
Jun 27 15:49:02 (none) user.debug kernel: [    3.089548] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: irq 45 for MSI/MSI-X
Jun 27 15:49:02 (none) user.debug kernel: [    3.089550] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: irq 46 for MSI/MSI-X
Jun 27 15:49:02 (none) user.warn kernel: [    3.092857] usb usb3: No SuperSpeed endpoint companion for config 1  interface 0 altsetting 0 ep 129: using minimum values
Jun 27 15:49:02 (none) user.info kernel: [    3.092864] usb usb3: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003
Jun 27 15:49:02 (none) user.info kernel: [    3.092866] usb usb3: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
Jun 27 15:49:02 (none) user.info kernel: [    3.092867] usb usb3: Product: xHCI Host Controller
Jun 27 15:49:02 (none) user.info kernel: [    3.092869] usb usb3: Manufacturer: Linux 2.6.38.4-pmagic xhci_hcd
Jun 27 15:49:02 (none) user.info kernel: [    3.092870] usb usb3: SerialNumber: 0000:04:00.0
Jun 27 15:49:02 (none) user.debug kernel: [    3.092961] xHCI xhci_add_endpoint called for root hub
Jun 27 15:49:02 (none) user.debug kernel: [    3.092963] xHCI xhci_check_bandwidth called for root hub
```

Well I have no idea what's going wrong, and I haven't had much luck from google and the forums so far. A number of unanswered threads with people with similar error messages and problems only.

Hopefully someone here can help or point me in the right direction?!

Answer (score 3):

add

```
blacklist uas
```

in the file `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

Comment: Thanks for this. Could you provide a little background on why that works, or why you think it would not be in there by default, etc? Are there any potential problems with adding that line? Thanks!

Comment: I'm also very curios what this does. I googled a bit, and found many similar posts suggesting to block UAS, e.g. [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/239782/connection-problem-with-usb3-external-storage-on-linux-uas-driver-problem) or [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/441668/debian-usb3-hdd-uas-i-o-errors). It seems to stand for "USB Attached SCSI (UAS)".