# hot-plugging USB 3.0 drive NOT working in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: usb-drive, hotplug

I have dell E6520 laptop with latest ubuntu 12.04. I also have the EC (ExpressCard) with the USB3.0 ports. The card is recognized by ubuntu (I can see in in lspci), but when I plug in the external USB3.0 HDD into the slot nothing happens - hot-plugging the drive does not work.

The same drive works as hot-plug into the USB2.0 port (built-in); it also works as USB3.0 if I plug it in before boot and boot with it plugged in.

How can I sort out this hot-plugging issue with USB3.0 ?

NOTE: when firstly installing ubuntu 12.04 the hot-plugging the same USB3.0 into the same EC car did work! It stopped working after upgrade to a new kernel.

Answer (score 2):

My usb3 drive was working until I did the update too. I fixed it by adding the line

```
blacklist uas
```

to the file `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`.

Hint found on:

- [External usb 3.0 hard drive is not recognised when plugged into usb 3 port](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50866/external-usb-3-0-hard-drive-is-not-recognised-when-plugged-into-usb-3-port)

This worked for me, once I rebooted and reattached the USB drive to my computer.