# My USB 3.0 port doesn't work

Tags: 14.04, usb, lsusb

Something is **very** wrong with usb support on Ubuntu. So, I have 2 USB 3.0 ports on the motherboard, along with 4 USB 2.0 ports and also 2 USB ports on my front panel. USB 3.0 isn't working and running `lsusb` and this is what happens:

```
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 058f:6366 Alcor Micro Corp. Multi Flash Reader
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04a9:2676 Canon, Inc. CAPT Device
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 043e:70d7 LG Electronics USA, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 18c3:6255  
Bus 004 Device 005: ID 04f3:0103 Elan Microelectronics Corp. ActiveJet K-2024 Multimedia Keyboard
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

How the hell is this even possible, I just switched from windows and I am starting to worry about driver compatiibility.

Perhaps this is something in the BIOS, but I don't know. Note: I don't know if relevant, but it boots through EFI (which is a good thing, I hope).

**Remark:** Previous ubuntu running on computer was either 13.04 or 12.10 and everything seemed normal then.

I have tried plugging in my gamepad, keyboard and mouse.

The ports seem to be powered though, I can charge my phone for example.

**As requested (nothing plugged in):** `lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RD890 PCI to PCI bridge (external gfx0 port B) (rev 02)
00:02.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RD890 PCI to PCI bridge (PCI express gpp port B)
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 40)
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:12.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 SMBus Controller (rev 42)
00:14.1 IDE interface: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 IDE Controller (rev 40)
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA) (rev 40)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 LPC host controller (rev 40)
00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 PCI to PCI Bridge (rev 40)
00:14.5 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI2 Controller
00:15.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB700/SB800/SB900 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 0)
00:15.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB900 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 3)
00:16.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:16.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 5
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Turks XT [Radeon HD 6670/7670]
01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Turks/Whistler HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 6000 Series]
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)
```

`lsmod`:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
xpad                   18218  0 
ff_memless             13573  1 xpad
btrfs                 835954  0 
raid6_pq               97812  1 btrfs
xor                    21411  1 btrfs
ufs                    74890  0 
qnx4                   13317  0 
hfsplus               107516  0 
hfs                    54677  0 
minix                  36140  0 
ntfs                   97369  0 
msdos                  17332  0 
jfs                   181348  0 
xfs                   912173  0 
libcrc32c              12644  2 xfs,btrfs
rfcomm                 69160  0 
bnep                   19624  2 
bluetooth             391196  10 bnep,rfcomm
nls_iso8859_1          12713  2 
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     46254  1 
joydev                 17381  0 
keucr                  72238  0 
uvcvideo               80885  0 
videobuf2_vmalloc      13216  1 uvcvideo
snd_usb_audio         153525  2 
videobuf2_memops       13362  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_core         40664  1 uvcvideo
snd_usbmidi_lib        29215  1 snd_usb_audio
videodev              134688  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core
usb_storage            62209  2 
usblp                  22891  0 
kvm_amd                59987  0 
kvm                   451511  1 kvm_amd
crct10dif_pclmul       14289  0 
crc32_pclmul           13113  0 
ghash_clmulni_intel    13216  0 
aesni_intel            55624  0 
aes_x86_64             17131  1 aesni_intel
lrw                    13286  1 aesni_intel
gf128mul               14951  1 lrw
glue_helper            13990  1 aesni_intel
ablk_helper            13597  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 20359  3 ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel,ablk_helper
snd_hda_codec_realtek    61438  1 
snd_seq_midi           13324  0 
serio_raw              13462  0 
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
edac_core              62291  0 
snd_hda_intel          52355  12 
fam15h_power           13119  0 
radeon               1522422  5 
edac_mce_amd           22617  0 
k10temp                13126  0 
snd_hda_codec         192906  3 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel
snd_rawmidi            30144  2 snd_usbmidi_lib,snd_seq_midi
snd_hwdep              13602  2 snd_usb_audio,snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               102099  5 snd_usb_audio,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
snd_seq                61560  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
snd_page_alloc         18710  2 snd_pcm,snd_hda_intel
snd_seq_device         14497  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              29482  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
sp5100_tco             13979  0 
ttm                    85115  1 radeon
i2c_piix4              22155  0 
drm_kms_helper         53081  1 radeon
snd                    69238  40 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_usb_audio,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_usbmidi_lib,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device,snd_seq_midi
drm                   303102  7 ttm,drm_kms_helper,radeon
i2c_algo_bit           13413  1 radeon
soundcore              12680  1 snd
mac_hid                13205  0 
parport_pc             32701  0 
ppdev                  17671  0 
lp                     17759  0 
parport                42348  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
hid_generic            12548  0 
usbhid                 52570  0 
hid                   106148  2 hid_generic,usbhid
pata_acpi              13038  0 
psmouse               106678  0 
r8169                  67581  0 
mii                    13934  1 r8169
ahci                   25819  3 
pata_atiixp            13271  0 
libahci                32560  1 ahci
```

Comment: Do they work if you plug them in and then reboot?

Comment: Let me try, wait a little. Also my kernel seems a little old.

Comment: Ahh the kernel may be the problem! What version do you have? `uname -r`

Comment: 3.13.0-32-generic. I just restarted and it shows something containing UVC for a moment, but boots quickly and OK. Maybe that has something to do with it.

Comment: Do you perhaps need specs?

Comment: Does the item work now?

Comment: Nope. BTW the devices are 2.0, but bios backward compatibility is enabled

Comment: I've looked up UVC, turns out it's got something to do with the webcam (which is plugged in the 3.0 port)

Comment: Strange that ubuntu doesn't detect it at all... http://askubuntu.com/questions/50866/external-usb-3-0-hard-drive-is-not-recognised-when-plugged-into-usb-3-port might help

Comment: @Tim well id did change something. The UVC disappeared, Cheese says  webcam error and my gamepad still doesn't work. Also to get the mouse moving I have to click it.

Comment: Also, it may be because of UEFI, can't it. I mean it shows a black screen for about 2 seconds and only after that it boots.

Comment: It could be... I'm afraid I don't have any more suggestions.

Comment: I solved this problem by loading xhci_hcd kernel module : `sudo modprobe xhci_hcd`

Comment: `lspci` and `lsmod` please...

Comment: @davidbaumann I've updated the question.